Cannot import existing resource group into terraform state due to 'configuration for import target does not exist'
I am configuring an Azure Resource group if it does not exist using this reference.
Below are the configuration files and error received.
Can I get some help on how to fix the error if possible?
main.tf
data "external" "rg_check" {
    program = ["/bin/bash","./script.sh"]
    query = {
        group_name = var.RG_NAME
    }
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_env" {
    count = data.external.rg_check.result.exists == "true" ? 0 : 1
    name = var.RG_NAME
    location = var.LOCATION
    provider = azurerm.org_env
}

script.sh
#!/bin/bash 

eval "$(jq -r '@sh "GROUP_NAME=\(.group_name)"')"
result=$(az group exists -n $GROUP_NAME)

jq -n --arg exists "$result" '{"exists":$exists}'

import.tf
import {
  to = azurerm_resource_group.rg_env
  id = "/subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/testrg"
  provider = azurerm.org_env
}

error in pipeline

data.external.rg_check:


Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.


Error: Configuration for import target does not exist. The
configuration for the given import azurerm_resource_group.rg_env does not exist. All target instances must have an associated configuration to be  imported.


##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: TerraformPlanFailed

